# Use facebook as (alternate user account) causing like button to disappear

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I noticed today that if I am logged in to facebook, and have selected one of my alternate business profiles (under the *, use facebook as) then it tries to put my original profile picture and a red box that says "switch" up on my pages that have the like button included using the javascript sdk, in place of the normal like button.

Here is an example of a page on which this happens: http://www.infolists.com/Arts/Painting/000000000128.php

Because I only leave enough space for the like button, it completely blows up my page layout.  So that everything in that layer falls behind the layer for the next line.

Unfortunately, you have to be logged in to facebook AND using it as an alternate profile (such as a business or fan page) to see the issue. Which I admit is rare and the reason I never noticed it before.

But there has got to be a workaround for this.  I've tried searching but couldn't find anyone else with the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Almost a week and no responses.  Is that because the group doesn't understand the issue?  Or that truely no one has ever faced this issue before?  

I did notice that some major sites (like marketwatch) also have this issue when the alternate facebook view being active.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, fan pages can only like objects within Facebook. The like button on websites are meant for personal profiles only.

Your only option to maintain the same layout would be to fix the div container of the like iFrame to a fixed height. The overflow hidden should also help (already set).